# How do I get a single result, from two tables, where the 2nd table contains an updated version of a record from the 1st?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I have two tables, `CompanyAddresses` & `MyCompanyAddresses`. *(Names changed to protect the guilty).*

`CompanyAddresses` holds a list of default addresses for companies. These records are immutable. The user can change the details of a company address, but those changes are stored `MyCompanyAddresses`.

How can I produce a single list of addresses from both tables, excluding records from `CompanyAddresses` where a corresponding record exists in `MyCompanyAddresses`?

#### Sample Data

CompanyAddresses

```
DatabaseId | Id    | Code | Name      | Street            | City      | Zip    | Maint Date
    1      | Guid1 | APL  | Apple     | 1 Infinite Loop   | Cupertino | 95014  | 11/1/2012
    2      | Guid2 | MS   | Microsoft | One Microsoft Way | Redmond   | 98052  | 11/1/2012
```

MyCompanyAddresses

```
DatabaseId | Id    | Code | Name      | Street            | City      | Zip    | Maint Date
    5      | Guid3 | APL  | Apple     | Updated Address   | Cupertino | 95014  | 11/6/2012
```

Desired Results

```
DatabaseId | Id    | Code | Name      | Street            | City      | Zip    | Maint Date
    2      | Guid2 | MS   | Microsoft | One Microsoft Way | Redmond   | 98052  | 11/1/2012
    5      | Guid3 | APL  | Apple     | Updated Address   | Cupertino | 95014  | 11/6/2012
```

I've tried various permutations of MS SQL's `UNION`, `EXCEPT` & `INTERSECT` to no avail. Also, I don't believe `JOIN`'s are the answer either, but I'll be happily proven wrong.

The database design *can* be changed, but it would be preferable if it stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN in combination with COALESCE. If the JOIN finds a match, the COALESCE will select values from the overridden row. If no match is found, the original values are returned.

```
SELECT ca.DatabaseId, 
       COALESCE(mca.Id, ca.Id) AS Id,
       COALESCE(mca.Name, ca.Name) AS Name,
       COALESCE(mca.Street, ca.Street) AS Street,
       COALESCE(mca.City, ca.City) AS City,
       COALESCE(mca.Zip, ca.Zip) AS Zip,
       COALESCE(mca.MaintDate, ca.MaintDate) AS MaintDate,
    FROM CompanyAddresses ca
       LEFT JOIN MyCompanyAddresses mca
           ON ca.Code = mca.Code;
```

Comment: DatabaseId isn't going to be the same across tables. I updated the question to reflect this. However, I do have a `Code` field that will be the same. I'll see how that plays with your suggestion.